# NASM programming - Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: arrays, x86, nasm

My program is very simple. It takes two input from the user:

1. an array (only 2 digit positive numbers)
2. a 2-digit number to be searched

output: number of times the given no. occurs in array

sample

> Enter the size of array
>   03
>   Enter a number
>   10
>   Enter a number
>   12
>   Enter a number
>   10
>   Enter the number to be searched
>   10

Your number appeared **02** times

everything seems to be working fine but this programs gives the error

> 0segmentation fault(core dumped)

Please help me solve this problem

```
enter code here

  section .data

 msg1: db "Enter the size of array",10    
 len1: equ $-msg1    

msg2: db "Enter a number",10    
len2: equ $-msg2     

msg3: db "Enter the number to be searched :"     
len3: equ $-msg3      

msg4: db "Your entered number appeared "    
len4: equ $-msg4    

section .bss      
temp: resb 1     
array: resb 100     
d1: resb 1      
d0: resb 1     
size: resb 1     
num: resb 1     
ele: resb 1     
time: resb 1     

section .text     

 global _start:     

 _start:      
 ;Getting the size of array     

 mov eax,4           
 mov ebx,1          
 mov ecx,msg1            
 mov edx,len1          
 int 80h             

 mov eax,3           
 mov ebx,0        
 mov ecx,d1         
 mov edx,1           
 int 80h              

 mov eax,3            
 mov ebx,0           
 mov ecx,d0           
 mov edx,2          
 int 80h            


 sub byte[d1],48           
 sub byte[d0],48          

 mov al,byte[d1]          
 mov bl,10           
 mul bl          
 add byte[d0],al             
 mov al,byte[d0]           
 mov byte[size],al           
 mov byte[temp],al             

 mov ebx,array          

 reading:           
 push rbx           ;preserves the value of ebx     


  mov eax,4   
  mov ebx,1  
 mov ecx,msg2   
 mov edx,len2   
 int 80h   

 mov eax,3   
  mov ebx,0   
 mov ecx,d1     
 mov edx,1    
 int 80h     

 mov eax,3    
 mov ebx,0    
 mov ecx,d0    
 mov edx,2    
 int 80h    

 sub byte[d1],48     
 sub byte[d0],48     

 mov al,byte[d1]     
 mov bl,10     
 mul bl     
 add byte[d0],al      
 mov al,byte[d0]      

 pop rbx         

 mov byte[ebx],al          
 add ebx,1          
 dec byte[temp]          
 cmp byte[temp],0            
 jg reading              

 mov eax,4              
 mov ebx,1          
 mov ecx,msg3            
 mov edx,len3            
 int 80h          

 mov eax,3         
 mov ebx,0         
 mov ecx,d1          
 mov edx,1          
 int 80h          

 mov eax,3       
 mov ebx,0            
 mov ecx,d0             
 mov edx,2          
 int 80h             

 sub byte[d1],48                 
 sub byte[d0],48              

 mov al,byte[d1]              
  mov bl,10             
  mul bl             
 add byte[d0],al                
 mov al,byte[d0]                  

 mov byte[ele],al              

 mov cl,byte[size]                
 mov byte[temp],cl              

 mov byte[time],0              

 search:             

 mov al,byte[ebx]             
 cmp byte[ele],al           
 jne nf               
 jmp f             
 mov cl,0


 f:   add ebx,1            
   add byte[time],1             
    dec byte[temp]           
   cmp byte[temp],cl           
    jg search          
    jmp next


 nf:        
     add ebx,1         
     add byte[time],0           
     dec byte[temp]       
     cmp byte[temp],cl          
     jg sea rch        
     jmp next


  next: 

  mov eax,4        
  mov ebx,1         
  mov ecx,msg4          
  mov edx,len4          
  int 80h           

  movzx ax,byte[time]           
  mov bl,10           
  div bl              
  mov byte[d1],al           
  mov byte[d0],ah          

   add byte[d0],48            
   add byte[d1],48         

   mov eax,4        
   mov ebx,1        
   mov ecx,d1            
   mov edx,1          
   int 80h           

   mov eax,4           
   mov ebx,1         
   mov ecx,d0           
   mov edx,1``        
   int 80h      

    mov eax,1      
    mov ebx,0        
    int 80h
```

Comment: I could start up a debugger here, but isn't that what you are supposed to be doing when learning how to write assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, I noticed one thing. I think your 'search' loop goes out of bounds because you failed to initialize register `cl`; the instruction `mov cl,0` is currently dead code; it is beneath an unconditional jump so it never ever gets executed.

But as I said earlier, when in doubt, use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

```
global _start
section .text
_start:

mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,msg
mov rdx,msglen
syscall

mov rax,0
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,no1
mov rdx,5
syscall

mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,msg1
mov rdx,msg1len
syscall

mov rax,0
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,no2
mov rdx,5
syscall

mov rax,[no1]
sub rax,30h
mov rbx,[no2]
sub rbx,30h
add rax,rbx
add rax,30h
mov [res],rax
mov rdx,2
syscall

mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,res
mov rdx,2
syscall

mov rax,60h
mov rdx,0
syscall

section .data
msg: db "Enter 1st Number",0x0a
msglen equ $ -msg
msg1: db "Enter 2st Number",0x0a
msg1len equ $ -msg1
msg2:db "Addition is==",0x0a
msg2len equ $ -msg2

section .bss
no1: resb 5
no2: resb 5
res: resb 15
```

Comment: Although this answer is old, I don't see how this answer helps since the question is 32-bit code and yours is 64-bit code. Even if it was useful code to answer the question It would also help if you offered up an explanation instead of just a code dump.